# How to retrieve a page which contains a city template in the infobox with the Wikipedia api

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, wikipedia-api

I want to fetch a page based on search but the page should contain the word "City" in the infobox. Is there a template for city?

This what i have done so far:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&format=json&formatversion=2&prop=pageimages%7Cpageterms&titles=London
```

Comment: AFAIK, there exists the `Template:Infobox settlement` template.

Comment: Following on from that, you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:WhatLinksHere/Template:Infobox_settlement to get a list of every article where that template is transcluded (> 500,000). You can get that via the API as well using https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=transcludedin&titles=Template:Infobox_settlement&tinamespace=0&format=json